# How to access a method from all classes inside a package without creating object in java

Tags: java, class, methods, scope

How can I access a method from all the classes inside a package without creating an object of that class.

> **Main Class**

```
public class mainclass
{
public void methodOne()
{
subclass obj = new subclass();
System.out.println("Height and Width" + obj.width()+" "+obj.height());
}
}
```

> **My second class**

```
public class subclass
{
public int width()
{
return (int)windowWidth;
}

public int height()
{
return (int)windowHeight;
}
}
```

Is it possible to call width() and height() without making the object of subclass

Comment: Why don't you want to create an instance of `subclass`?

Answer (score 2):

Well, no, to put it succinctly. There's no way to call these methods without changing something.

You could mark the methods `static`, and then they could be called without creating an object. But then if `windowWidth` and `windowHeight` were instance members, you wouldn't be able to access them, so the code of the methods themselves wouldn't compile. Then they wouldn't be the same methods anymore, obviously -- so the answer is still, really, no.

Comment: **Thanks Ernest Friedman-Hill** 
That solved my problem
I Made the method to be static and ow i can call width() and height() from mainclass()
thanks again

Answer (score 1):

No. For non-static methods you need an instance to call them on.

Comment: **Thanks Thilo** 
That solved my problem
I Made the method to be static and ow i can call width() and height() from mainclass()
thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You have to make an instance of an object to call its methods.  Unless the method is on the invoking object.

***EDIT***

The above is true *only* for non-static methods.  Static methods, on the other hand, can and should be accessed on the class level (i.e. not instance required).

Comment: **Thanks Tim Pote..** 
That solved my problem
I Made the method to be static and ow i can call width() and height() from mainclass()
thanks again

Comment: Does of us get the accepted answer?  Maybe whoever go there first?  (@Akash in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to declare that method as static if you want to use that without creating the instances of that particular class

Comment: **Thanks Akash Yadav** 
That solved my problem
I Made the method to be static and ow i can call width() and height() from mainclass()
thanks again